# Joint conditional distribution

Tags: conditional-probability

Hey I have a question where i think i am doing everything correct but I don’t get the expected solution, I think the solution may be wrong - or I am....

[image]

Calculate P(0I1) and P(1I1)

for $$P(X=1|Y=1) =P(X=1,Y=1)/P(Y=1)=0.3/0.5=3/5$$

And $$P(X=0|Y=1) = P(X=0,Y=1)/P(Y=1)= 2/5$$

But this is apparently not correct.... maybe you could tell me if i am wrong or not...

Many thanks

Comment: What is $P(0 | 1)$? You have to specify which random variable gave $0$ and which gave $1$, e.g. $P(X = 0 | Y = 1)$.

Comment: Please use MathJax. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: It might help if you also wrote your own working in more detail. For example in $0.3/0.5$ there is no indication why you wrote those particular numbers $0.3$ and $0.5.$ It looks like they should be probabilities of something, but you should say what.

Comment: You are plugging wrong numbers in your last calculations ...

Comment: @DavidK I added additional info, many thanks for your help

Comment: @Math-fun I edited it, it is now how i believe is correct.

Comment: After the edit that swapped the $0$ and $1,$ I agree with your calculations.

Comment: @DavidK many thanks the solution says 0.8 and 0.2.... it is so frustrating if you calculate for the nth time and still can’t find what is wrong

Comment: Looks good to me.  Obvious check, sum of answers = 1.

Comment: $0.8$ and $0.2$ would make sense if it were $P(X=0\mid Y=0)=0.8$ and $P(X=1\mid Y=0)=0.2.$ But if it says $Y=1$ then I think your results are the correct ones. It is possible the answer key is wrong--doesn't happen very often, but it does happen sometimes.